# Why does the Hamiltonian density transform as a scalar field and not as the zeroth component of a vector field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, poincare-symmetry

Page 191 of Weinberg Vol.1. Break the Hamiltonian operator up into two parts $H=H_0+V$, where $H_0$ is the free Hamiltonian and $V$ is the interaction. Write the interaction operator $V(t)$ as a local integral of some interaction density $h(x,t)$ (Eq. 5.1.1 of Weinberg)
\begin{equation}
V(t)=\int d^3 x^i\,\, h(x^i,t)
\end{equation}
Now Weinberg imposes that the interaction density should transform as a *scalar* field (Eq 5.1.2 of Weinberg)
\begin{equation}
U(\Lambda)h(x^{\mu})U^{-1}(\Lambda)=h(\Lambda^{\mu}_{\,\,\nu}\, x^{\nu})
\end{equation}
This is in contradistinction with my understanding that the interaction density is the zeroth component of a four vector, and hence would lead me to expect that it should transform as:
\begin{equation}
U(\Lambda)h(x^{\mu})U^{-1}(\Lambda)=(\Lambda^{-1})^{0}_{\,\,\alpha}p^{\alpha}(\Lambda^{\mu}_{\,\,\nu}\, x^{\nu})
\end{equation}
In the last line I have defined a "momentum density field" whose zero component is the interaction density $p^0(x^{\mu})=h(x^{\mu})$.

**Question:** Why does the interaction density transform as a scalar field and not as the zeroth component of a 4-vector field?

Comment: You're confusing the Hamiltonian as the Legendre transform of the Lagrangian and the energy as a component of the 4-momentum, those are two different objects which need not be equal.

Comment: In the context of Weinberg Chp5 $H=H_0+V$ here is to be viewed purely as one of the generators of the Poincare algebra, namely that of time translation. It follows from the Poincare algebra that the translation operators transform as the 4-vector representation $U[\Lambda]P^{\mu}U^{-1}[\Lambda]=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu}P^{\nu}$. So it is definitely the case that the total $H=H_0+V$ transforms as the zeroth component of a four vector, the only question is how the $V$ should transform. Weinberg claims it should be a scalar.